# copy all files with jpg/jpeg extension in specific sub categories to single directory

Tags: linux, bash, find, cp

I have a directory structure as below

- product_images

  - product1

    - LR

      - low res images here
    - HR

      - high res images here
  - product2

    - LR

      - low res images here
    - HR

      - high res images here
  - product3

    - LR

      - low res images here
    - HR

      - high res images here

I want to copy all images with extension jpg/jpeg in the HR folders to a single directory.

I tried to modify `find . -type f \( -iname "*.jpg" -o -iname "*.jpeg" \) -exec cp '{}' /cpjpg \;` but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Remove the quotes around `{}`.

Comment: `I tried to modify … but nothing seems to be working.` – Did you get any feedback? Please [edit] the question and include the exact (modified) command(s) and error messages they print (if any). The "base" command looks sane but it may "succeed" in a somewhat confusing way when `/cpjpg` is not a directory or it doesn't exist initially. So make sure your target is a directory.

Comment: @xenoid I think the quotes don't make a difference. Why do you think they do?

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
find . -type f -ipath "*/HR/*.jp*g" -exec cp -i {} /cpjpg \;
```

I used `cp -i` to not automatically overwrite existing files.